# custom post type post post_count not working , i prefer display 4 post but now only 1

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a page template and try to echo the custom post type "products" from template parts
but when I publish the page its only display one post of products only, I prefer display 4 post :(

```
get_header();

 // Reference global $post variable.
global $post;

// Get posts.
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_count' => 4
));  

// Set global post variable to first post.
$post = $posts[0];

// Setup post data.
setup_postdata( $post );

// Output template part.
get_template_part( 'template-parts/products' );

// Reset post data.
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: use `numberposts`

Comment: `// Set global post variable to first post.` – so where exactly are you doing this (and the following steps) for the other three posts then …? If you want to do anything multiple times, then the coding should obviously contain some sort of loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like this

```
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 4   
);
$loop = new WP_Query($query);
```

I hope this is helps you

Answer (score 0):

**Change your code like this**

```
get_header();

 // Reference global $post variable.

 global $post;

// Get posts.
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 4
));  

// Set global post variable to first post.
$post = $posts[0];

foreach($posts as $post){
// Setup post data.
setup_postdata( $post );
}

// Output template part.
get_template_part( 'template-parts/products' );

// Reset post data.
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**hope this will helps you**

Answer (score 0):

Your query is structured incorrectly as others have mentioned, the best practice I've always known is to use the WordPress loop. Hope this helps!

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 4   
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts()):while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post(); {
 // write your code
}
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```